# jniLibs are not extended in gradle

Tags: android, gradle

An android application have two modules and one depend on the other, and the common used jars and native libraries are defined in `parent-project`, while the `child-project` add it as a dependency in the build.gradle:

[image]

However after I build the `child-project` I found that the `jars` put insiede the `parent-project` are copied to the apk, while the native libraries are not. Only the native libraries inside the `child-project` are packaged to the apk.

What's going on?

With Android studio 1.0.2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue. The problem was, in my parent (library) project's build.config's sourceSets I've added the following:

```
jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']
jni.srcDirs = []
```

This didn't work, .so files were missing from the child project's APK, so I've replaced it with:

```
jni.srcDirs = []
jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
```

With this method, everything is fine.

Comment: Great answer. +1   To those who are using build-native.sh for your projects please note that once you have the .so files generated please copy the generated ABI .so files to src -> jniLibs. After that update gradle to jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/jniLibs']. Else you will get unsatisfied link error when you download your git project in another location because .gitignore will usually have the modulelibs folder!

Also do check-in the src/jniLibs to git so that the .so files are permanently available in repository, without having to build .so files every time you clone a new local repository.