# ExceptionInInitializerError Physics World

Tags: android, andengine

I searched in a number of forums and it seems to be a common question. However i couldnt find a solution. I didnt do anything crazy so it seems stange that this happens.

```
@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {
    Scene s = new Scene();
    PhysicsWorld mWorld=new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH),true);
    s.registerUpdateHandler(mWorld);
    final Sprite eliSprite = new Sprite(400, 240, james_walking[3], getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    eliSprite.setScale(0.5f);
    s.attachChild(eliSprite);
    s.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
    return s;
}
```

I dont have much more to say because i dont know much about Andengine so a dummies explanation would be apreciated.
   After adding what you said the error goes out, however the PhysicsWorld still doesnt work. THe logcat says

```
02-27 17:07:51.153    2590-2639/com.company.m.appname D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.company.m.appname/lib/libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so 0x41cdce70, skipping init
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably native libraries (.so files from lib dir) is missing from your APK. Check your project settings / build configuration.

If you're using android studio, you have to modify the sourceSet of andEngine and andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension in build.gradle.

You have a folder in that projects where there are so files, you need to include the native libraries from there.

Check my answer here: [jniLibs are not extended in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247955/jnilibs-are-not-extended-in-gradle)

Update based on your comments:

Add this to andEngine, andEnginePhysicsBox2d and your game build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
    }
}
```

Also add this to the defaultConfig section, for andEngine:

```
ndk {
   moduleName "andEngine"
}
```

and for andEnginePhysicsBox2d:

```
ndk {
    moduleName "andEnginePhysicsBox2dExtension"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but how do i check that?

Comment: Do you build your project with eclipse or intellij/android studio?

Comment: I don't know the folders in your andEngine project because it can be using the eclipse hierarchy, which it's in the libs folder, and it can use the new hierarchy. Check for .so files in andEnginePhysicsBox2D.

Comment: ok, I have a libs/aremabi_v7a folder where there is one  .so in the andEnginePhysicsBox2D module. what should i do with it?

Comment: Well, the error is gone but the PhysicsWorld still doesnt work,

Comment: My bad! forgot the physics connector

Comment: Error:(5, 0) Could not find property 'jni' on source set 'main'.
<a href="openFile:/Users/someuser/AndroidStudioProjects/SomeProject/andEngine/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: so to be specific, sourceSets should be inside android section, and i change jniLibs.srcDir 'libs' to jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'