# How to add the libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so file in Android Studio | Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I wanted to develop an app with Android Studio using the Andengine. After I have imported the andengine.jar and the libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.jar everything seemed to work correctly. At the point where the PhysicsWorld is created:

```
private void createPhysics() {
        physicsWorld = new FixedStepPhysicsWorld(60, new Vector2(0, -17), false);
        registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);
    }
```

this exception appears: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sample.packet.sample-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so"`

I think I must download the *.so file but I don't know where to place it in my project. Could anyone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750746/exceptionininitializererror-physics-world/28752626#28752626

Answer (score 1):

you can follow my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34068202/2026280

or

Its very simple. Follow this simple steps

**1)** Create a new folder called **"lib"** inside the libs folder of the **main app**.

**2)** Copy all the folders ie.armabi , armabi-v7a etc from **andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension/libs** folder, and paste in in the previously created **"lib"** folder in **main app**.

**3)** Now compress the **"lib"** folder as **"lib.zip"** and rename it to **"lib.jar"**.
this changes the **zip** extension to **jar**.

**4)** Finally add a line -- **compile files('lib.jar')** under dependencies{} in **Build.gradle** file of your **main app**.

**5)** Clean and build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is located in a directory under you application.

file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/71lxz2ec9qrn236/libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so?dl=0

[image]

Comment: This file for all architecture .??