# couldn't find "libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so"

Tags: android, android-studio, andengine

I am making simple android app using andengine and box2d extention.
Unfortunately, I got this message:

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/es.esy.m3na71jnu5cg5e2.gs14049_bsj_mid-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=        [/data/app/es.esy.m3na71jnu5cg5e2.gs14049_bsj_mid-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so"
              at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
              at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
              at org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<clinit>(PhysicsWorld.java:35)
              at es.esy.m3na71jnu5cg5e2.gs14049_bsj_mid.PvPActivity.onCreate(PvPActivity.java:70)
              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I added .so files according to other answers, but I can not solve this problem.
[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvrxy.png)

build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

            defaultConfig {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi"
            }
            applicationId "es.esy.m3na71jnu5cg5e2.gs14049_bsj_mid"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
        compile files('libs/org_andengine_extension_physics_box2d.jar')
        compile files('libs/org_andengine.jar')
        compile files('libs/lib.jar')
    }
```

please help

Comment: When does this occur? When you try to compile your Android app or even try to run it.

Comment: It occured when I run this app. Exactly, this error occurs when Activity containing declaration of new PhysicsWorld is runned.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, but with another library; have you been able to solve your problem?