# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I have tried to implement Android-FFmpeg-Images-Video android studio project example from 
reference [link](https://github.com/jdpxiaoming/Android-FFmpeg-Images-Video).

When I try to run the android application then here it will give error

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime. IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/data/com.catcry.ffmpeg/lib, /vendor/lib,/system/lib]]] couldn't find "libffmpeg-jni.so"

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");
    System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg-jni");
}
```

**This is my build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ffmpeg"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile project(':ffmpeg4android_os')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

**This is My Directory Structure**

[image: Dir]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just turn off instant-run from Setting/Preferences -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run
and uncheck the first two check-boxes. This error is because of instant-run feature.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved it by creating a folder structure as image below showing.

Copy your `.so` files to `armeabi-v7a`.

[image: this is project view]

This is android view>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UnsatisfiedLinkError is due to the libffmpeg-jni.so file missing on your android project. Please try for correct library.

Comment: Thanks for kind of response  I have that file in my project but still it will give error.   What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']

        jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
    }
}
```

does not corresponds to your folder structure.
Put 'jniLibs' under 'src/main' folder.

You can check this SO post for folder structure.
[jniLibs are not extended in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247955/jnilibs-are-not-extended-in-gradle)